# Stop a loop from going on after a specific number of decimal places

Tags: loops, numbers, double, square-root

I have a program that calculates the square root of a number without the Math.sqrt method. I made this but..... if the number is not a perfect square, the loop goes on forever (rightfully), how do I get the loop to stop after a number of decimal places in basic java :)
Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareRootMethod {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a number to square root: ");
    double Number = sc.nextInt();
    double Answer = FindSquareRoot(Number);
    System.out.println(Answer);



}



public static double FindSquareRoot(double NumberToRoot) 
{

    double Guess = NumberToRoot;
    double GuessAmmount = NumberToRoot;

    do
    { GuessAmmount = GuessAmmount/2;
    if (Guess*Guess >NumberToRoot);
    { Guess = Guess - GuessAmmount; }
    if (Guess*Guess <NumberToRoot)
    {Guess = Guess + GuessAmmount; }
    }
    while (Guess*Guess != NumberToRoot);
    return Guess;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting some sort of precision on the number?

```
public static double findSquareRoot(double numberToRoot) {
    double guess = numberToRoot;
    double guessAmount = numberToRoot;

    do {
        guessAmount = guessAmount / 2;
        if (guess * guess > numberToRoot) {
            guess = guess - guessAmount;
        }
        if (guess * guess < numberToRoot) {
            guess = guess + guessAmount;
        }
    } while (Math.abs((guess * guess) - numberToRoot) > 0.001);

    return guess;
}
```

The trick is on the `while` line.

Comment: Thanks! It worked..... buttt... I don't know how that works :). Could you just explain what that while line does?

Comment: Basically, your problem is that your condition: `Guess*Guess != NumberToRoot` will never be true for some numbers, so you'll run into an infinite loop.

Comment: So instead of requiring an exact number match, what I suggested was to calculate the difference between the number you want, and `guess * guess`. If they're close enough (based on a defined threshold), then we're happy and exit the loop. Does that make sense?